# Erratic behavior of WebView2 regarding fragment links

Tags: c#, winforms, webview2

I'm experimenting with the WebView2 browser and have encountered behavior I can't explain:
I have created a desktop fragment link which points to an anchor in a local html file.
When I drag the link to the browser control, if the control is empty (the app has just started), it won't navigate at all and shows about:blank#blocked in the address bar; a second attempt will sometimes open the link correctly. If not, dragging a text file to the control and then dragging the fragment link always succeeds.
Can someone clarify the matter?
Thanks in advance.